# Rest API - how add custom headers?

Tags: android, resttemplate, android-annotations

I want to make POST request with custom header. I can't find information how to do this using AA Rest API - https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API .

Should I use ClientHttpRequestInterceptor, which is used for authenticated requests? 
https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Authenticated-Rest-Client

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently an open issue for this : https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/323

For now, the only way to do this is with a custom ClientHttpRequestInterceptor. Here is a little example :

```
@EBean
public class CustomHeaderInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] data, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        request.getHeaders().add("myHeader", "value");
        return execution.execute(request, data);
    }

}
```

Then, you need to link it to the restTemplate, like this :

```
@EBean
public class MyService {

    @RestService
    RestClient restClient;

    @Bean
    MobileParametersInterceptor mobileParametersInterceptor;

    @AfterInject
    public void init() {
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
        interceptors.add(mobileParametersInterceptor);
        restClient.getRestTemplate().setInterceptors(interceptors);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have to use the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor for custom header.
Currently, it's the only way I know.

See the official [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/) of Spring-Android for more informations about the RestTemplate.