# Add custom header to REST PUT request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have an application that uses Spring Boot 2.1.8 with an Angular front end.  I have defined my repositories using @RepositoryRestResource.  The Spring Boot app basically provides a REST API for the Angular piece.  The application defines several business entities and the REST respo provides CRUD functionality for each entity.  Here is a typical repo interface for one of those entities:

```
// REST resouce /api/privgroups
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "privgroups", path = "privgroups")
public interface PrivGroupRepository extends CrudRepository<PrivGroup, Long>
{
   List<PrivGroup> findAll();
}
```

GETing and single entity, POSTing (creating an entity) and PUTing (updating an entity) are all working fine, but I would like to return a custom header when updating (HTTP PUT) an entity.  The header would be consumed by the Angular side to display a custom toastr message specific to that entity.  Since the repositories also implement the REST interface I am unsure how to add a specific header that would change based on the target entity.

I have developed applications that include a REST controller that calls against a service which in turn calls against a repository.  In this case, I have more control and can easily return custom headers like so:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> updateMyEntity(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity)
{
    MyEntity updatedEntity = this.MyEntityService.updateMyEntity(MyEntity);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header("X-Save", "MyEntity")
        .body(updatedEntity);
}
```

Is there a newer "built-in" technique I can use to achieve this?  I know I can add headers using a filter and I've read a couple posts on the subject.  I think it would be difficult to identify the entity being updated and I'm unsure this is the best approach.

NOTE that this post:
[Rest API - how add custom headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566893/rest-api-how-add-custom-headers)
is really old.
The spring data rest docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/
don't have anything specific on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Spring Data Rest recently and I didn't find any "built-in" technique for that. However you can achieve that by implementing the ***ResponseBodyAdvice*** interface in a class annotated with ***@ControllerAdvice***. This is how I got it:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class PutMyEntityBodyAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {

        // Write the condition to check if beforyBodyWrite should be called
        return returnType.getParameterType().equals(ResponseEntity.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object object, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
                                  Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType,
                                  ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {

        // Check if it is a PUT request for MyEntity object
        if (HttpMethod.PUT.equals(request.getMethod()) && object instanceof PersistentEntityResource) {
            PersistentEntityResource persistentEntityResource = (PersistentEntityResource) object;
            if (persistentEntityResource.getContent().getClass().equals(MyEntity.class)) {
                // Add custom header or manipulate response object
                response.getHeaders().add("X-Save", "MyEntity");
            }
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this technique worked well for me.  I was able to isolate my header changes into a single class and also easily added POST related headers too.

Comment: Note that HTTP DELETE operations do not work with this method.  I believe this is because the Spring Data REST interface for http DELETE does not return an object of type ResponseEntity.  In fact, DELETE operations should return "no content" 204.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @pepevalbe looks promising.

An alternative might be - as you suggested - using a standard Servlet Filter or Spring HandlerInterceptor.

To address the issue of getting a reference to the modified entity in that case you could register a Spring Data Rest event listener that would simply store a reference to the modified entity in ThreadLocal storage from where it could be retrieved in the Filter or HandlerInterceptor.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events.application-listener